# How to use origin value in substrate pallet

Tags: rust, blockchain, ethereum, substrate, metamask

The `ensure_signed` function of `pallets/template/lib.rs` contains a parameter named `origin` of type `OrginFor<>`. I have been looking inside various projects and all I see is doing `ensure_signed(origin)?`.

My question is how actually should I get something like public key or wallet address from that origin value. I believe something must be inside `Signed(AccountId)` variant. But in test files of several examples and tutorials all i see is they simply pass `Origin::Signed(1)`. What am I supposed to do with that 1?

I am pretty starting out in these blockchain things so any kind of knowledge is highly appreciated

Comment: The `ensure_signed` function returns an `AccountId`, aka Public key.  
Test use `Origin::Signed(1)` to create a mocked origin for `AccountId` 1.  
Edit for pressing Enter too early.

Comment: So in runtime I will get some public key inside Signed instead of just 1?

Comment: Yes for example [here](https://github.com/perun-network/perun-polkadot-pallet/blob/39a6176cb4a78aac329bddd6d9dc8b307b03fea7/src/lib.rs#L225) you can see that `who` is an `AccountId` and is later used to transfer funds from.

Comment: As you said, given that who is an AccountId, who can I compare it to some other source (vec/array of u8 in my case) to see if the who and that source are same.